# Prove that $EX=E(E(X|Y))$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Prove that $EX=E(E(X|Y))$

I know that I should prove it from definition of conditional distribution and conditional expected value, but I don't know how.

I have also looked at theorem("Total expectation") which should be connected with the proof.

If someone would tell me, which properties of expectation I should use to prove it, I would be really glad.

Comment: Do you want a proof for the discrete case or the general one? Have you studied measure theory?

Comment: In the wiki page of Law of total expectation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) there is a proof...

Comment: I haven't study measure theory. For discrete one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}  \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|Y)) & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(X|Y = y) f_Y(y) dy \\ & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X|Y}(x|y) dx \ f_Y(y) dy \\ & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)  f_Y(y) dx dy \\ & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X,Y}(x,y)   dx dy \\ & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X,Y}(x,y)   dy dx \\ & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)   dy dx \\ & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_{X}(x) dx \\ & = & \mathbb{E}(X) \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: in the first equality, how do you know that the outer expectation is with respect to Y?

Comment: Thank you. How you get $f_Y(y)dy$ in the first line please?

Comment: Thank you Amit. What is the goal behind this rule?

Comment: Also, can you please show what is subscript $f_{X|Y}$ under function and how it becomes later $f_{X,Y}$. Also, how you concluded that integral of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)$ please?

Comment: @bob I have used LOTUS i.e. $\mathbb{E}(g(Y)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y) f_Y(y) dy$

Comment: @Avv Conditional density of $X$ given $Y=y$ is defined as: $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$. I have just used that.

Comment: @Avv This is because integral of the joint density with respect to $y$ gives marginal density of $X$ i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x, y) dy = f_X(x)$

Comment: Is it because the integral over  variable $y$ gives 1 (sum of all probabilities) please?

Comment: Bob might have finished a degree in between their question and your answer =))))
BTW, thanks for your complete answer. It helped me.

Answer (score 7):

By definition $E(X\mid Y)$ is random variable which satisfies:
$$
E(X \cdot 1_G) = E\bigl(E(X\mid Y)\cdot 1_G\bigr), \quad \text{for all} \ G \in \sigma(Y).
$$
Simply take $G=\Omega$ such that $1_G=1$ and you get the desired result.