# Given $\mathbb E(5X+2)=12$ and $\mathbb E(X|Y)=Y^3$ compute $\mathbb E(Y^3)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

Given $\mathbb E(5X+2)=12$ and $\mathbb E(X|Y)=Y^3$ compute $\mathbb E(Y^3)$.

I've been trying this a million different ways and can't seem to reach a final answer, I would love any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Answer (score 7):

$$\mathbb E(5X+2)=5\,\mathbb E(X)+2=12 \implies \mathbb E(X)=2$$

$$\mathbb E(Y^3)=\mathbb E\bigl(\mathbb E(X|Y)\bigr)=\mathbb E(X)=2$$

Comment: For any readers: Reference [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2110224) to see that $\mathbb E\bigl(\mathbb E(X|Y)\bigr)=\mathbb E(X)$.

Answer (score 2):

$E[X] = 2$.

Since $E[ X|Y] = Y^3$, then $E[Y^3] = E[ E[X|Y]] = E[X] = 2$.