# Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be i.i.d. RVs and let N be another independent RV which takes values from nonnegative integers. Let $Y=\sum_{k=1}^N X_k$

Tags: probability

Using the fact that $M_Y(t)=M_N(logM_{X_1}(t))$, derive $$E[Y]=E[N]E[X_1]$$

I don't quite see how to use the hint to prove this. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the hint, law of total expectation and independence of $X_i$ and $N$.

Comment: Is it an obligation to use that fact? If not then leave it aside (it is only complicating things) and just go for $\mathbb EY=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\mid N]]$. It surely does not deserve the label "hint".

Comment: @drhab Can you take a look Vizag's answer. In particular, the questions in the comments.

Comment: Also, doesn't conditional expectation require that  $E[|N|]< \infty$?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta I have commented the answer of Vizag and wrote an answer myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiate both sides in $t$ and set $t=0$ to get your answer

$\frac{d}{dt}M_Y(t)|_{t=0} = E[Y]$.

$\frac{d}{dt}M_N(\log M_{X_1}(t))|_{t=0} = \frac{M_{X_1}'(t)}{M_{X_1}(t)}M_N'(\log M_{X_1}(t))|_{t=0} = \frac{E[X]}{1}M_N'(0) = E[X]E[N]$

Answer (score 1):

First we observe that: $$\mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^NX_k\mid N=n\right]=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]=n\mathbb EX_1$$where the first equality *is based on the independence* of $N$ wrt the $X_k$.

From this we conclude that: $$\mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^NX_k\mid N\right]=N\mathbb EX_1$$

The last step is:$$\mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^NX_k\right]=\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^NX_k\mid N\right]\right]=\mathbb E[N\mathbb EX_1]=\mathbb EX_1\mathbb EN$$

Comment: Very clear now! Thank you! I still have to think a bit about the first equality though, but is intuitively certainly correct.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simpler way to do this BTW, just for the record.

$$E(Y) = E(E(Y|N))$$

$$E(Y|N) = E(\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{k})$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^{N} E(X_{k})$$
$$=N\times E(X_1)$$

Therefore,

$$E(E(Y|N)) = E(X_1)\times E(N)$$

Comment: Why can you interchange sum and expectation? N (upper sum index) itself is a random variable.

Comment: We calculated it first for a given $N$. The Linearity of expectations holds always. Then we treated $N$ as random variable in the last step.

Comment: I am not entirely sure this is allowed: $E[\sum_{k=1}^N X_k] = \int_\Omega \sum_{k=1}^{N(\omega)} X_k(\omega) P(d\omega)$ and you claim that you can put the sum outside. But the upper summation depends on $\omega$, thus can't be put outside. I think you need more than what you did, but I'm no probability expert.

Comment: You also didn't use independence, which I believe will be crucial here. This suggests your approach contains a mistake.

Comment: Formal proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108697/prove-that-ex-eexy/2110189

Comment: That's not the step I'm worried about... I know that's true and that I don't debate. It is easily proven via Radon-Nikodym or $L_p$ space theory.

Comment: Equalities $\mathbb E(Y\mid N)=\mathbb E(\sum_{k=1}^NX_k)=\sum_{k=1}^N\mathbb EX_k$ are not correct. The first and last expression both stand for a random variable. The middle expression stands for a real number.